# I wanted to integrate the geo fencing with google maps API v2, so how can i?

Tags: geofencing, android-maps-v2

I am new to google maps, my requirement is to create the virtual boundaries on google maps API V2 using geo fencing. I wanted to make an alert when the virtual boundaries are crossed.
So how can i get this done or any useful information regarding it?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way how we implemented that is that we created background service which wakes up periodically (every 5 mins for instance) and checks you current location. 
Tricky point here is to avoid using GPS data to save battery, but use network location data instead.
As far as I know, there is no native way to create geofencing like in iOS